# How can i see git commit id from TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit to commit my project files. I want to see my commit ids of all my commits. Is it possible to see commit id of my last commit using TortoiseGit UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immediately after commit the new commit id is displayed (in the first line `master` is the current branch and `39b9f7d` is the commit id of the current commit):

[image: Commit status]

When you want to see all history and all previous commit ids, you can open the log dialog, by using the context menu in explorer and chose TortoiseGit → Show log (you might need to select "Show whole project" or open the log on the working tree root, otherwise the log content might be tailored to the selected file/folder). Then the following dialog appears:

[image: Log Dialog]

There you can see the commit id (SHA1) in the textbox below the commit list. You can also open the context menu on the list header and select "sha1" - then the commit ids are also shown directly in the list.

Also see: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html

If you just want to see the latest commit id, you can also open the Windows Explorer properties and select the Git tab, there you can see the SHA-1 of the current `HEAD`.

Comment: While selecting a commit from log, the textbox shows SHA-1 value. Is that SHA-1 is commit id ?

Comment: @safinchacko Yes

Comment: Thanks you @MrTux